# customized join output

Tags: vertica

Example consider two tables Persons and Employee

Persons table sample:

```
Name,Address
1. john,new York
2. Diana,new jersey
```

Employee table sample:

```
Employee ID,Team
1. 123,developer
2. 568,tester
```

Required join Table output should be like

```
Name,Address,Employee ID,Team
 1.john,new York,null,null
 2.Diana,new jersey,null,null
 3.null.null,123,developer
 4.null,null,568,tester
```

I want above sample as output is there any way to solve this issue.

Comment: You may want to explain the logic behind the expected output, because it's not very clear. Please take a look at [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

This can work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM Persons a
LEFT JOIN Employee b ON 1=2
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Persons a
RIGHT JOIN Employee b ON 1=2;
```